# For which parameter values is the determinant of a matrix zero?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let
  $$A_k=\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 1 \\
    k-1 & 0 & k \\
    -1 & k+3 & 4
  \end{bmatrix}$$

Find all real numbers $k$ such that $\det(A_k) = 0$.

Can anyone help me on this question please?

Comment: expand you determinant. Your question will become in this way a question of roots of a quadratic in $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the middle column of matrix $A_k$ has two elements equal to $0$, I would exploit that to calculate its determinant
$$\det(A_k)=-(k+3)(2k-(k-1))=-(k+3)(k+1)$$ Now, it must be fairly easy to find the $k$'s for which $\det(A_k)=0$.

Comment: Still not sure. I tried getting the det of this like a normal 3x3 matrix and got k(-k-4)-3 as the det. So not sure what number will make that a 0

Comment: $k(-k-4)-3=-(k+3)(k+1)$, so...

Comment: So k would be -3 or -1?

Comment: Yes, exactly...